# How to press enter to close this AngularJS dialog notify box?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog

I am using this angular dialog service https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service which looks better than javascript alert().

I am using the notify dialog. An example (with source code) which I forked from the original can be found below;
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Abizv

When you click on the `Notify Dialog` button, the dialog appears. What I want to do is to press enter key to close the dialog. However, this cannot be done. I have to press Esc key to press the dialog. How can the code be changed to close the dialog by pressing Enter?

Comment: angular-dialog-service does not give any option to support this type of functionality. But it is a wrapper on ui.bootstrap.modal. You can open a custom dialog and then you can handle Enter key in that custom dialog's controller and can fire manual dialog close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the event taking place to a function, if angular.equals(evt.keyCode, 13) you call the close function. 
keyCode 13 is enter key